# Toilet tank fills only when I turn on/off the shut off valve

Tags: bathroom, toilet, valve, shutoff

After years of working perfectly, one morning my toilet stopped filling. All at once. The problem is as follows:

The toilet flushes correctly, but the tank does not fill. No water is coming into the tank.

I turn off the shut off valve, then turn it back on, and the tank fills correctly. I can repeat this Twilight Zone scenario time and time and time again. No change.

To date, I have replaced the shut off valve (the pressure was strong - got a few facefuls of water when I mistakenly turned the valve on while tightening the nut).

I also flushed the hose running from the shut off valve to the tank (it's clean as a whistle and the gaskets at both ends look healthy).

Any help you can give I'd really appreciate it. I can find no satisfying answer online for this bizarre problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I would turn off the water.  Remove the shut off valve and place a hose/tubing on the pipe to a bucket/toilet bowl.  Turn on the water and see is something comes out.

Comment: Thanks, but I did replace the shut off valve.

Answer (score 1):

This is classic when a toilet fill valve get particles stuck inside.  You can try to open the top and clean the valve, but experience dictates that usually replacing the fill valve is what finally fixes the problem.

Comment: The flush valve? Inside the tank. Okay, that sounds like it might fit the bill. Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Comment: The FILL valve...the valve the water line is attached to outside of the tank. I mistakenly typed FLUSH in my answer. I will correct that.

Comment: It WAS the fill valve. Thank you so much! What great advice. Thanks!

Comment: Y W.   Please click the check to the left of the answer to show you choose it as correct.